# I got this error message when i'm deploying instant app on play store

Tags: android, apk, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

[image]

Hey guys can anyone here to help to resolve this issue
I'm working on instant app and when I'm deploying the instant app on play store I got this error my instant app zip size is 4mb[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what an `APK` is that ? 4Gb+

Comment: no i'm talking about instant app apk

Comment: As per my understanding, “mapped” error is because you are missing an intent-filter that’s mapped to “atmosphare.eventbuoy.com”, and your “not linked” error is because Google Play detects a mismatch between the hosted assetlinks.json and your app. Please also see https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links.html

Answer (score 5):

Because you have **limit 4MB**:

[Official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#apk-size)

> What does the 4MB total download limit mean?
>
> The size of the instant app (base feature plus any included dependent
>   feature) should be as small as possible. The smaller your app, the
>   easier it is for the users to download. However, once the instant app
>   is running on the user's device, you can download additional data and
>   store it in the internal storage. There is no 4MB hard limit for
>   storing data in the internal storage of the device.
>
> To calculate the size, unzip the Instant App APK and examine the APK
>   APK files. You can either use the disk size of the APK files or open
>   the APK Analyzer and check the Raw File Size value.
>
> For an instant app with multiple features, you must add the size of
>   the base feature APK to a single feature APK. The total size of both
>   these APKs must be under 4MB.

**To avoid that you can** :

- use [Proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) to remove some unused code;
- move some resources from your apk to your server;
- compress images in your apk via for
  example [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/)(free service) or [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/)(offline library);

Comment: but row file size is 3.2, download size also 3.2.both are below 4mb
please help I'm stuck here..I'm already wasted a whole day

Comment: @SumitKumawat GooglePlay said that your apk from your question has 4 418 297 bytes.
And please read in my answer how you should calculate the size.

Comment: @SumitKumawat You also can do installable version of your apk with limit 100MB instead instant apps version

Comment: @SumitKumawat I advise you to do the currently installed version (with a limit of 100MB), since you have the first version of your application, and you have already reached the limit of 4 MB.

Comment: ok, I got what you want to said......but i'm facing some issues                                Your site 'atmosphare.eventbuoy.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.
You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'atmosphare.eventbuoy.com' via a web 'intent-filter'.

Comment: @SumitKumawat I suggest to you create a new question with this new issue. And please don't forget accept my answer if it was useful for you.